# Verificar se a string contém outros tipos de caracteres

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que trabalha com expressões lógicas, por exemplo recebe como entrada:

```
((TvF->T)^(T->F))->(~F<->T)
```

aí faço toda a validação para retirar espaços em branco, substituir `->` por `-` e `<->` por `-`.

Como posso fazer uma validação na string de expressão para verificar se o usuário digitou algum outro caractere que não seja algum desses:

```
(,T,v,F,->,<->,~,),^?
```

Comment: Você quer só detectar ou quer remover tambem?

Comment: Regex no método `String.matches( ... )` para verificar se há caracteres inválidos

Comment: Gostaria de detectar apenas, para avisar o usuário que ele informou uma expressão inválida. O matches eu usaria no caso String.matches("(TvF^~");  para ele retornar se encontrou outras coisas além desses caracteres na string?

Comment: Não acho que essa validação seria suficiente, porque você vai precisar validar se a expressão está coerente também; por exemplo, validar que todos os parênteses foram fechados e que estão corretamente aninhados. Acho que você vai precisar implementar um _analisador léxico_.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para validar se as os caracters são válidos pode fazer algo do género:

```
    String operation = "((TvF->T)^(T->F))->(~F<->T)";
    Set<String> validStrings = new HashSet<String>(
        Arrays.asList(new String[]{ "(", "T", "v", "F", "->", "<->", "~", ")", "^", "?" })
        );
    Set<Character> combinedChars = new HashSet<Character>(
        Arrays.asList(new Character[]{ '-', '<' })
        );

    boolean isValidOp = true;
    StringBuilder subString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < operation.length(); i++) {
        subString.append(operation.charAt(i));
        if (validStrings.contains(subString.toString())) {
            subString = new StringBuilder();
        } else {
            if (!combinedChars.contains(operation.charAt(i))) {
                isValidOp = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(isValidOp);
```

Mas para o que validação de expressões lógicas será necessário algo mais, tal como mencionaram nos comentários teria que garantir que por exemplo os parênteses são fechados quando abertos.